# How can I access props inside Context consumer

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to send a prop with this code

```
const CreateActivity = () => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser =>
      <CreateActivityShow match={this.props.match} email={authUser.email}/>
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  )
```

it gives me the following error

this3.props is undefined

I need to pass url parameters inside  this.props.match, any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with the following code

```
  export default props =>  (
<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  {authUser =>
    <CreateActivityShow {...props} email={authUser.email}/>
  }
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>
)
```